# 404 Error With Django Rest Framework ViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

Im still new with Django Rest Framework, I want to filter the queryset using an URL parameter.

Here's my **models.py**:

```
class Offre(models.Model):          
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default=0)
    secteur = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    idRecruteur = models.ForeignKey(Recruteur,verbose_name = "idRecruteur", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Offre: {}".format(self.title)
```

Here's what i did in **urls.py**:

```
router = DefaultRouter();
router.register(r'OffresByRecruteur/(?P<idRecruteur_id>\d+)/$', OffreRecruteurViewSet, base_name='inoutreports')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Finally **api.py**:

```
class OffreRecruteurViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Offre.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OffreSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.queryset.filter(idRecruteur_id=self.request.GET.get('idRecruteur_id'))
```

This generates

```
Using the URLconf defined in djangular.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
   ^scrumboard/ ^OffresByRecruteur/(?P<idRecruteur_id>\d+)/$/$ [name='inoutreports-list']
   ^scrumboard/ ^OffresByRecruteur/(?P<idRecruteur_id>\d+)/$\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='inoutreports-list']
   ^scrumboard/ ^OffresByRecruteur/(?P<idRecruteur_id>\d+)/$/(?P<idRecruteur>[^/.]+)/$ [name='inoutreports-detail']
   ^scrumboard/ ^OffresByRecruteur/(?P<idRecruteur_id>\d+)/$/(?P<idRecruteur>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='inoutreports-detail']
The current path, scrumboard/OffresByRecruteur/1/, didn't match any of these.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex for registering the viewset should not end with `/$`. Rest framework will [add the slash](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#api-guide) by default, and you don't want the dollar because it matches the end of the string.

```
router.register(r'OffresByRecruteur/(?P<idRecruteur_id>\d+)/', OffreRecruteurViewSet, base_name='inoutreports')
```

Secondly, when you get the queryset, you should get `idRecruteur_id` from `self.kwargs`. You would use `self.request.GET` to fetch from the querystring, e.g. if the URL was `/scrumboard/OffresByRecruteur/?idRecruteur_id=1`.

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.queryset.filter(idRecruteur_id=self.kwargs['idRecruteur_id']))
```